# Отправить и вывести без обновления страницы

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Здравствуйте, как сделать, чтобы при отправке сообщения у получателя оно высвечивалось сразу, то есть без обновления страницы и динамического обновления. 
Писали что-то про WebSocket, но так и не смог разобраться в них.

Помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему, а то посетители жалуются на динамическое обновление...

Вывод сообщений:

```
    <?php
$myid = $myuser[id]; //Мой ID
    $messs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mess WHERE (idUser='$myid' OR idRecipient='$myid') AND (idUser='$idussd' OR idRecipient='$idussd')");
            while ($mess = mysql_fetch_array($messs)) {
                $text = $mess[text];
                $date = date('d.m.y H:i', $mess[date]);
                $musers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$mess[idUser]'");
                while ($muser = mysql_fetch_array($musers)) {
                    if ($muser[avatar] == '0') {
                        $avus = 'user.png';
                    } else {
                        $avus = "avatars/".$muser[avatar];
                    }
                    if ($mess[status] == '0') {
                        $statstylenoread = "style='background-color: #C8D7EA;'";
                    } elseif ($mess[status] == '1') {
                        $statstylenoread = "";
                    }
                    echo "<div class='message-reply-container-im' $statstylenoread>
                        <div class='message-reply-avatar-im'>
                            <a href='/profile/".$mess[idUser]."/'>
                                <img src='/images/".$avus."'>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class='message-reply-message-im'>
                            ".$text."
                            <div class='message-time-im'>
                                <span>".$date."</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>";
                }
            }
    ?>
```

Отправка сообщения:

HTML:

```
<div class='gomessbl'>
    <div class='chat-form-inner'>
        <div id='idus' style='display: none;'>$_GET[id];</div>
        <input id='txtmess' placeholder='Введите сообщение...'>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(erim){ //Отправить сообщение
      document.querySelector('#txtmess').addEventListener('keydown', function(erim){
        if('key' in erim) {
          if(erim.key.toLowerCase() !== 'enter') {
            return;
          }
        } else {
          if(erim.keyCode !== 13) {
            return;
          }
        }
          var id = $("#idus").text();
          var txtmess = $("#txtmess").val();
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '/obr/mess.php',
              data: 'idus='+ id +'&txt='+ txtmess,
              success: function(data) {
                if (data == '1') {




$("#txtmess").val("");
            } else {
              alert(data);
            }
          },
          error: function(xhr, str){
                alert(data);
            }
        });

  });
});
```

PHP (/obr/mess.php):

```
<?php
include("../connectdb.php");

$idus = $_POST[idus];
$text = $_POST[txt];
$date = time();


$cluss = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users WHERE id='$idus'");
$clus = mysql_fetch_array($cluss);

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$myusers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ip='$ip'");
while ($myuser = mysql_fetch_array($myusers)) {
    $myid = $myuser[id];
}

$clmesss = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM mess WHERE (idUser='$myid' OR idRecipient='$myid') AND (idUser='$idus' OR idRecipient='$idus')");
$clmess = mysql_fetch_array($clmesss);




if (empty($text)) {
    echo "";
} else {
    if ($clus[0] == '0') {
        echo "Ошибка. Такого пользователя не существует";
    } else {
        if ($clmess[0] == '0') {
            $numcode = $myid."-".$idus;
        } else {
            $messs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mess WHERE (idUser='$myid' OR idRecipient='$myid') AND (idUser='$idus' OR idRecipient='$idus') LIMIT 1");
            while ($mess = mysql_fetch_array($messs)) {
                $numcode = $mess[gripixname];
            }
        }
        $plusmess = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mess (idUser, idRecipient, status, text, date, photo, gripixname)
                                            VALUES ('$myid', '$idus', '0', '$text', '$date', '$photo', '$numcode')");
        echo "1";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать следующим образом:

В файле-обработчике ajax запроса (/obr/mess.php) вместо `echo "1";`
вставьте:

```
$result = array(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2,
    // добавьте в этот массив все необходимые для вывода на странице данные
);

// выдаем ответ в виде JSON строки
echo json_encode($result);
```

В JS, в функции ajax() добавьте параметр `dataType: 'json'`

После этого вы получите в

```
success: function(data) {
    // data - JS объект с полученными от сервера данными
    // {key1: value1, key2: value2}
    // обработайте их необходимым образом
}
```

Comment: Вы видимо не поняли. Мне надо, чтобы как в БД приходило сообщение, его сразу выводило на страницу.
Типа как в вк диалоги: Пользователь 1 отправил сообщение и у собеседника оно сразу высветилось не перезагружая страницу и без динамического обновления. А echo "1" даёт понять, что всё хорошо прошло